# how to add an offset and limit with join query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter ,and I have done the below code

```
public function members($limit, $offset)
{
$this->load->model('Management/Member_model', 'member');
    $this->db->reset_query();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->member->table);
    $this->db->join('ib_communities_dtl','ib_communities_dtl.dtl_user_id='.$this->member->table.'.user_id','inner');
    $this->db->join('ib_communities','ib_communities_dtl.dtl_community_id=ib_communities.community_id','inner');
    $this->db->where('ib_communities.community_id', $this->community_id);

  return $this->db->get()->result('Member_model');
}
```

I want to add offset and limit to the above query , can anyone help me modify it to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: read the manual https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results

Answer (score 5):

```
public function members($limit, $offset)
{
$this->load->model('Management/Member_model', 'member');
    $this->db->reset_query();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->member->table);
    $this->db->join('ib_communities_dtl','ib_communities_dtl.dtl_user_id='.$this->member->table.'.user_id','inner');
    $this->db->join('ib_communities','ib_communities_dtl.dtl_community_id=ib_communities.community_id','inner');
    $this->db->where('ib_communities.community_id', $this->community_id);
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);

  return $this->db->get()->result('Member_model');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add offset and limit in [CI limit](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results) function as:

```
$this->db->limit(LIMIT,OFFSET);
```

**Example:**

```
public function members($limit, $offset)
{
    $this->load->model('Management/Member_model', 'member');
    $this->db->reset_query();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->member->table);
    $this->db->join('ib_communities_dtl','ib_communities_dtl.dtl_user_id='.$this->member->table.'.user_id','inner');
    $this->db->join('ib_communities','ib_communities_dtl.dtl_community_id=ib_communities.community_id','inner');
    $this->db->where('ib_communities.community_id', $this->community_id);
    $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);  //CHANGED
    return $this->db->get()->result('Member_model');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed the following function in the the query builder section :

```
$this->db->limit(10, 20); // specifying the limit and the offset
```